# Somehow notifying converter that collection has changed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

This converter is my indirect issue, or specifically the ObservableCollection user_modules within it. This converter is attached to a set of buttons.

When my app starts the collection is empty, all buttons are disabled, then when the user logs in it is populated. However the view and viewmodel are not notified that the collection has changed, the buttons remain disabled when they should not. How do I do this?

I believe the following three sections of code are fine, but I am not sure of fourth, I believe this is where I need to do alterations.

```
public class IsEnabledMultiValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            bool userHasAccess = false;
            int Module_ID = (int)values[0];
            ObservableCollection<UserModuleLevel> user_module_levels = values[1] as ObservableCollection<UserModuleLevel>;
            UserModuleLevel userModuleLevel = user_module_levels.SingleOrDefault(um => um.Module_ID == Module_ID);

            if (userModuleLevel != null)
            {
                userHasAccess = true;
            }

            return (userHasAccess);
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

My XAML:

```
<Button.IsEnabled>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource converter}" >
       <Binding Path="Module_ID" />
       <Binding Path="DataContext.UserModuleCollection"
                RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}" />
    </MultiBinding>
</Button.IsEnabled>
```

My ViewModel: Once the user logs in UserModuleLevels with _current_user are populated.

```
public ObservableCollection<UserModuleLevel> UserModuleCollection
{
    get { return CurrentUser._current_user.UserModuleLevels; }
}
```

User class which holds the collection:

```
public class User
{
    public User(){}

    public int User_ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<UserModuleLevel> UserModuleLevels = new ObservableCollection<UserModuleLevel>();
}
```

Comment: You aren't using a converter in an appropriate way. What you want to do is setup a `Command` on the button with a `CanExecute` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve here but what I can get is *you want the converter to be called whenever item is added or removed from the list*.

If that's the case, you can **have another binding in your XAML under MultiBinding which will bind with `Count` of ObservableCollection**. `Count` will be updated whenever item is added/deleted. So, you can have that just to get notified.

```
<Button.IsEnabled>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource converter}" >
       <Binding Path="Module_ID" />
       <Binding Path="DataContext.UserModuleCollection"
                RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}" />
       <Binding Path="DataContext.UserModuleCollection.Count" <-- Only to refresh
                RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}" />
    </MultiBinding>
</Button.IsEnabled>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Convert` method of your converter will not be executed when the observable collection is populated. That is because only ItemsControls like `ListBox` or `ComboBox` listen to the `CollectionChanged` event of the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface. But this wouldn't be applicable for you problem.

If I understand your code correctly, I would advise you to create a new ViewModel class that is instantiated for every button. In it you specify the module ID and if the user is able to use it (the check you currently perform in your converter). Bind each button to a new instance of that view model.

I hope this helps. If you have any questions, please leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Two points stand out as possible causes. You say when the user logs in the modulelevels are populated?
So initially CurrentUser and subsequent module levels will be null?
You may need to raise a notification event when the Currentuser and its UserModuleLevels are set.

Additionally, in the fourth section you set th private variable to be new, but the property also has a setter, with no notification event. If you are subsequently setting that property you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged. Or make it read-only by removing the setter.

```
     public class User:INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public User(){}

            public int User_ID { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            private ObservableCollection<UserModuleLevel> user_module_levels = new ObservableCollection<UserModuleLevel>();

            public ObservableCollection<UserModuleLevel> UserModuleLevels
            {
                get
                { return user_module_levels; }
                set
                { 
                  user_module_levels = value; 
                  this.OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

                [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
                protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
                {
                    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
                    if (handler != null)
                    {
                        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                    }
                }

        }
```